# Let $x > 0$. Prove that the value of $\int^{x}_{0} \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt + \int^{\frac{1}{x}}_{0} \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$ does not depend on $x$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Let $x > 0$. Prove that the value of $$\int^{x}_{0} \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt + \int^{\frac{1}{x}}_{0} \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$$ does not depend on $x$.

I really have no idea how to start this problem. How do I show something doesnt "depend" on something?

Comment: Take the derivative with respect to $x$ would be a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second integral, let $t=1/u$ to get

$$\int_0^{1/x}\frac1{1+t^2}\ dt=\int_x^\infty\frac1{1+(1/u)^2}\frac{du}{u^2}=\int_x^\infty\frac1{1+u^2}\ du$$

Add it to the first integral to get

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+t^2}\ dt=\frac\pi2$$

which does not depend on $x$.